# For a given triangle, prove that $DL=DM$

Tags: geometry, triangles

In a triangle $ABC$, $D$ is midpoint of the side $BC$. Through the point $A$, $PQ$ is any straight line. The perpendiculars from the points $B$, $C$ and $D$ on $PQ$ are $BL$, $CM$ and $DN$ respectively. Prove that $DL = DM$

Can someone give me hint as how to use the information, '$D$ is the mid point of BC'? We can use the fact that $BL,DN,CM$ will be parallel to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\triangle LDN = \triangle MDN (LN=MN, ND - common, \angle LND  = \angle MND= 90^{\circ}  ) \Rightarrow DL=DM$

$DN - $ the middle line of the trapezoid $BLMC$ ($BL||DN||CM$ and $BD=CD$)
[image]

Comment: How is $LN=MN$?

Comment: $DN - $ the middle line of the trapezoid $BLMC$

Answer (score 0):

[image]
$BL||DN||CM$ and $BD=CD$

By intercept theorem $LN=LM$
Clearly $\triangle LND$ and $\triangle MND$ are congruent by S-A-S

So,$ DL=DM $ (Corresponding parts of congruent triangles)